# Finding the radius of convergence $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$ and properties of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$.

(a)  Show that the radius of convergence is $1$.

Let $1/\rho=\limsup\sqrt[n]{|z^{n!}|}=\limsup|z|^{(n-1)!}$.  This is how far I got.

(b)  Let $g(z)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$ on the open unit disk centered at the origin.  Show that this is analytic and show that for every rational $q$, $|g(re^{2\pi i q})|\to \infty$ as $r \to 1$ from the left.

To show this is analytic, we simply note that $z^{n!} < z^n$.  Then by the Weierstrass M-Test this converges both uniformly and absolutely on the unit disk.  Hence it converges on any compact subset of the unit disk.  So it also converges normally.  Thus it is analytic.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If $|z|<1$, the series converges absolutely by comparison to the usual geometric series. If $|z|\geqslant 1$, the $n$-th term doesn't go to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For $r<1$ the series in $ z=r$ is convergent, by comparison against the geometric series: $R\ge 1$. For $z=1$ it is divergent, so $R=1$.
2. First question should be in your notes. 
   For the second one: there is some $n_0$ such as
   $$
   n\ge n_0\implies qn!\in \Bbb N\\
   \implies \exp(2i\pi qn!) = 1\\
   \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty (r\exp(2i\pi qn!))^{n!}
   =\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty r^{n!}\to\infty
   $$when $r\to  1$.

Comment: How would I see the radius of convergence from the formula I provided?

Comment: $\limsup a_n^\frac 1n = 1$ because $a_n$ take only 0 and 1 values, each infinitely often. Look carefully, you formula is wrong: there should not be any $z$ in it!

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient, C_k=1 for k=1!,2!,3!...
Use it further.

Comment: For the second part. Take z=1, in particular. The series is 1+1+1+... which is divergent. How can you use this? Recall that power series is continuous within the radii of convergence